# Как отобразить по умолчанию форму для ввода комментариев (wordpress-сайт) на страницах записей произвольного типа?

Tags: php, wordpress

На вордпресс-сайте зарегистрирован произвольный тип записей: movies

Создан шаблон single-movies.php для отдельной страницы записи типа "movies"

- Регистрация произвольного типа записей "movies" осуществлена с помощью кода (в файле functions.php):

  ```
  add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');

  function my_custom_init() {
      // Регистрация произвольного типа записей "movies"
      $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Фильмы', // Основное название типа записи
        'singular_name' => 'Фильм', // отдельное название записи типа movies
        'add_new' => 'Добавить новый',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новый Фильм',
        'edit_item' => 'Редактировать Фильм',
        'new_item' => 'Новый Фильм',
        'view_item' => 'Посмотреть Фильм',
        'search_items' => 'Найти Фильм',
        'not_found' => 'Фильмов не найдено',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине Фильмов не найдено',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Фильмы'
      );
      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments')
      );
      register_post_type('movies', $args);
      // Регистрация произвольного типа записей "movies"
      // end
    }
    // Добавляем фильтр, который изменит сообщение при публикации при изменении типа записи movies
  add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'movies_updated_messages');

  function movies_updated_messages($messages) {
    global $post, $post_ID;

    $messages['movies'] = array(
      0 => '', // Не используется. Сообщения используются с индекса 1.
      1 => sprintf('movies обновлено. Посмотреть запись movies', esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
      2 => 'Произвольное поле обновлено.',
      3 => 'Произвольное поле удалено.',
      4 => 'Запись movies обновлена.',
      /* %s: дата и время ревизии */
      5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf('Запись movies восстановлена из ревизии %s', wp_post_revision_title((int) $_GET['revision'], false)) : false,
      6 => sprintf('Запись movies опубликована. Перейти к записи movies', esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
      7 => 'Запись movies сохранена.',
      8 => sprintf('Запись movies сохранена. Предпросмотр записи movies', esc_url(add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID)))),
      9 => sprintf('Запись movies запланирована на: %1$s. Предпросмотр записи movies',
        // Как форматировать даты в PHP можно посмотреть тут: php.net/date
        date_i18n(__('M j, Y @ G:i'), strtotime($post - > post_date)), esc_url(get_permalink($post_ID))),
      10 => sprintf('Черновик записи movies обновлен. Предпросмотр записи movies', esc_url(add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID)))),
    );

    return $messages;
  }

   // показ раздела "помощь" для типа записей movies
  add_action('contextual_help', 'add_help_text', 10, 3);

  function add_help_text($contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen) {
    //$contextual_help .= var_dump($screen); // используйте чтобы помочь определить параметр $screen->id
    if ('movies' == $screen - > id) {
      $contextual_help =
        'Напоминалка при редактировании записи movies:
  Указать нужную информацию.
  Если нужно запланировать публикацию на будущее:
  В блоке с кнопкой "опубликовать" нажмите редактировать дату.
  Измените дату на нужную, будущую и подтвердите изменения кнопкой ниже "ОК".
  ';
    }
    elseif('edit-movies' == $screen - > id) {
      $contextual_help =
        'Это раздел помощи, показанный для типа записи movies';
    }
    return $contextual_help;
  }
  ```

  Для того, чтобы отобразить форму для ввода комментариев на странице записи произвольного типа "movies", - в шаблоне single-movies.php добавляем стандартную функцию: `<?php comments_template(); ?>`

  В результате на отдельной странице записи типа "movies" вместо формы для ввода комментариев - отображается текст: `Обсуждение закрыто.`
- При этом в случае с записями стандартного типа - при использовании функции `<?php comments_template(); ?>` - корректно отображается форма для ввода комментариев.
- В админке во вкладке "Настройки обсуждения" - установлена галочка "Разрешить оставлять комментарии на новые статьи"
- Не установлена галочка "Автоматически закрывать обсуждение статей старше 14 дней"
- Не установлена галочка "Пользователи должны быть зарегистрированы и авторизованы для комментирования."
- В админке непосредственно на странице редактирования записи произвольного типа - отображается блок "Обсуждение". В нем есть два чекбокса: "Разрешить комментарии." ; "Разрешить обратные ссылки и уведомления."

По умолчанию в чекбоксе "Разрешить комментарии." - галочка не поставлена.

Если галочку поставить вручную - то тогда на странице записи произвольного типа "movies" форма для ввода комментариев отобразится корректно. Однако форма для ввода комментариев отобразится только на странице одной конкретной записи, для которой в админке вручную поставили галочку в чекбоксе "Разрешить комментарии.", а не на всех страницах записей произвольного типа "movies".

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы в чекбоксе "Разрешить комментарии." галочка была бы по умолчанию проставлена для всех записей произвольного типа "movies" ? (чтобы форма для ввода комментариев отображалась бы по умолчанию на страницах записей произвольного типа?

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно обновить комментирование для постов в админке вот так:

1. In SETTINGS > DISCUSSION uncheck the "Allow people to post comments
   on new articles" setting.
2. Click "Save Changes"
3. Now go back and re-check "Allow people to post comments on new
   articles"
4. Click "Save Changes"